# How to check if nodejs process failed due to a timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, timeout, child-process

I spawn a synchronous process like this:

```
child = spawnSync('somecommand', { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: someDir, timeout: 30000});
```

Is there a reliable way to check if the child process failed due to the timeout option or some other error?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the log of node which is running down there somewhere. You must be running this with a cli so you can see the log there. Or you can look for where the log is saved. Everything, specially the errors are noted there.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into the same problem, there is a simple way to retrieve the timeout error code at run-time:

```
 if (child.error && child.error.code === "ETIMEDOUT") {
   console.log("child timed out");
 }
```